# sign in with google account in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-account

i am trying to use the API for "sign in with Google account" with my asp.net vb website just like [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or [FriendFeed](http://friendfeed.com) sign in with google. Please let me know if any one implemented it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check out the [OpenID Membership Provider](http://www.codeplex.com/OpenIDMembership) from Codeplex

> OpenID Membership Provider is an
>   ASP.Net Membership provider and login
>   control that is compatible with the
>   OpenID Authentication 2.0
>   implementation.

There is also OAuth implementation for .NET (to use with twitter and such services) http://oauth.net/code/.